# Filtering on Foreign Keys in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a few models in Django where I attach a location to each blog published:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.TextField()

class Town(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    town_name = models.CharField(max_length=192)

class Blog(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
```

I'm trying to filter them on country name but I'm getting "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression" when I try the following:

```
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter( town.country.country_name = 'Canada' ).order_by( '-id' )
```

Any ideas on how I could filter based on the country name?

Comment: 1 year later the answer is still not accepted !!.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
blog_list = Blog.objects.filter( town__country__country_name = 'Canada' ).order_by( '-id' )
```

Comment: And the documentation regarding this answer is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: What will be the time complexity?